# Command timeout with db2

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, db2

I am trying to set timeout for a dbcommand, and test it that is why timeout is set to 1.

This is the code I am using but timeout never fires, am I doing something wrong?

NOTE: DbConnection is used because this code is an extract from a generic code used not only for db2 so db2connection is not an option.

```
String lProviderFactory = "System.Data.OleDb";
String lStrConexion = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=PYRAMID;Hostname=192.9.200.13;Protocol=TCPIP; Port=50000;Uid=db2admin;Pwd=xxx;";
String lQuery = "SLOW SELECT";
var lDbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(lProviderFactory);
DbConnection mConexion = lDbFactory.CreateConnection();
mConexion.ConnectionString = lStrConexion;

mConexion.Open();

try
{
    DbCommand lComando = mConexion.CreateCommand();
    lComando.CommandText = lQuery;
    lComando.CommandTimeout = 1;


    DbDataAdapter lAdapter = lDbFactory.CreateDataAdapter();
    lAdapter.SelectCommand = lComando;
    DataSet lDs = new DataSet();
    lAdapter.Fill(lDs);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPCION :" + ex.Message); //Timeout should fall in here
}
finally
{
    mConexion.Close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How slow is `SLOW SELECT`?  Is it possible it's not slow enough?  Don't blanket-catch exceptions, even (especially) in tests - you may be hiding something.  Your test should probably fail if `lDs` is populated - If you're not using a testing framework, throw `IllegalState` or similar.

Comment: Your point is good, I certainly don't know (or find) a good way to be sure how long the query takes to be resolved. I measured time it took to execute fill and it were 10 seconds but timeout didn't occur. About the exception you are right, thanks for the tip.